# Proxy analytics requests

Tags: apache, google-analytics

We are exploring turning on google analytics for our web applications however they are served behind a rather restrictive CSP which it will be difficult to extend. As an alternative I have explored using ProxyPass to send the requests through an Apache server within the CSP white-list.

The Apache server contains these directives:

```
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
ProxyPass /google https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect
ProxyPassReverse /google https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect
```

The client code replaces the BuildHitTask in order to call `https://white-listed.server.com/google + '?' + Payload` All looks fine in the client however it fails to reach that endpoint, receiving a 404 response. If I open the generated tracking link separately sure enough I see a 404 response from Google:

```
The requested URL /r/collect was not found on this server. That’s all we know.
```

Any thoughts on where this is going wrong or if it is even possible?

Answer (score 0):

OK, having wrangled with the problem a little more it seems that we have resolved the issue with the addition of the `ProxyPreserveHost Off` command.